# PHP filter_validate_int for numbers with preceding zero

Tags: php, filter-input

I want to use PHP's filter_input with FILTER_VALIDATE_INT to validate time in hours and minutes apart. the problem is that this function returns false when the time is like 03:07

```
$hours_range = array (
'options' => array (
    'min_range' => 0,
    'max_range' => 23
)
);

$minutes_range = array (
'options' => array (
    'min_range' => 0,
    'max_range' => 59
)
);

filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'hour', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $hours_range)

filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'minute', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $minutes_range)
```

Comment: Isn't it the colon that is causing trouble?

Comment: I usually get the DateTime class to do this sort of validation as part of a callback filter.

Comment: Nm, missed something in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm... You could try another filter here - I would probably try `FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP`. Maybe something like:

```
$mins = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'hour', FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, ['options' => [
    'regexp' => '/\d{1,2}/']
]);
```

Just adding the regex `\d{1,2}` as an example here, clearly you might want to define something better here. Alternatively you could use `FILTER_CALLBACK` and define a callback inside which you can check if your value is an `int` and explicitly within your required numeric range.

Comment: Nice touch with regexp.